anchor_lang::Owner` is not implemented for `anchor_spl::token_interface::Mint
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::Token;
use anchor_spl::token_interface::Mint;

declare_id!("FtUL5xL7oZasB5zaDUETbeHs9jcf9gopQD3Z1V92YyKv");

pub mod constants {
  pub const VAULT_SEED: &[u8] = b"vault";
  pub const STAKING_INFO_SEED: &[u8] = b"staking_info";
  pub const TOKEN_SEED: &[u8] = b"token";
}

#[program]
pub mod solana_staking {

  pub fn staking_deposit(context: Context<InitializeStaking>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let user_public_key: Pubkey = context.accounts.user.key();
    msg!("From {:?}", user_public_key);
    msg!("Amount {:?}", amount);
    Ok(())
  }

}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeStaking<'info> {
   #[account(mut)]
   pub user: Signer<'info>,

   #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = user,
    seeds = [constants::VAULT_SEED],
    bump,
    token::mint = mint,
    token::authority = token_vault_account
   )]
  pub token_vault_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
  pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
  pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Staking {
  pub user: Pubkey,
  pub amount: u64,
}



If you want to use anchor_spl::token_interface::Mint, you'll need to use InterfaceAccount, ie:
  pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

But in your case, since you're passing in Program<'info, Token> and not Interface<'info, Token>, you might be better off just using anchor_spl::token::Mint instead of its interface version.
